# Spring Boot + Apache ShardingSphere + MyBatis - Error creating bean with name 'shardingDataSource' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sharding

I'm trying to make a POC on apache shardingsphere with spring boot and mybatis. But i'm unable to start the tomcat server on my local.

Here is my pom.xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ShardingPOC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <relativePath/>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.shardingsphere</groupId>
                <artifactId>shardingsphere-jdbc-core-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.shardingsphere</groupId>
                <version>4.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <version>8.0.28</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>31.0.1-jre</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.8</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is my application.yaml contents:

```
server:
  port: 9090
spring:
  shardingsphere:
    datasource:
      names: test0,test1
      test0:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        hikari:
          auto-commit: true
          connection-timeout: 20000
          idle-timeout: 10000
          max-lifetime: 1000
          maximum-pool-size: 10
          minimum-idle: 10
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test0?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
        username: root
        password: root@12345
      test1:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        hikari:
          auto-commit: true
          connection-timeout: 20000
          idle-timeout: 10000
          max-lifetime: 1000
          maximum-pool-size: 10
          minimum-idle: 10
        jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
        username: root
        password: root@12345
    # Repository Configuration
    sharding:
      tables:
        student: # Table name of the repository
          actual-data-nodes: test$->{0..1}.student    # Fragmented data node configuration, Grovvy expression, for test0, test1
          # Repository Configuration
          database-strategy: # Repository Policy Configuration
            inline: # inline represents the row expression strategy, as well as other slicing strategies
              sharding-column: rollNum # 
              algorithm-expression: test$->{rollNum.toInteger() % 2}   # Fragmentation policy, rollNum divides 2 moulds
    props:
      sql.show: true # Console Print SQL
```

I created two databases test0 and test1 each of them have a student table and i want to shard the api request based on the student rollNum column.

Here is my mapper interface:

```
@Mapper
public interface StudentMapper {
    @Insert("insert into student (studentId, rollNum, name, address, adhaarNum, laptop) " +
            "values (#{studentId}, #{rollNum}, #{name), #{address}, #{adhaarNum}, #{laptop})")
    void insert(Student student);
}
```

Here is the db scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `studentId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rollNum` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adhaarNum` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `laptop` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rollNum_UNIQUE` (`rollNum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Here is the StarterApp file:

```
@MappedTypes({Student.class, Laptop.class})
@MapperScan("com.practice.mapper")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.practice"})
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class StarterApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StarterApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

server startup logs:

```
2022-04-26 14:39:38.589  INFO 42043 --- [           main] com.practice.StarterApp                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-04-26 14:39:40.527  INFO 42043 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'stringToNoneShardingStrategyConfigurationConverter' of type [org.apache.shardingsphere.spring.boot.converter.StringToNoneShardingStrategyConfigurationConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-04-26 14:39:40.543  INFO 42043 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.shardingsphere.sharding-org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.sharding.SpringBootShardingRuleConfigurationProperties' of type [org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.sharding.SpringBootShardingRuleConfigurationProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-04-26 14:39:40.546  INFO 42043 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.shardingsphere.masterslave-org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.masterslave.SpringBootMasterSlaveRuleConfigurationProperties' of type [org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.masterslave.SpringBootMasterSlaveRuleConfigurationProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-04-26 14:39:40.550  INFO 42043 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.shardingsphere.encrypt-org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.encrypt.SpringBootEncryptRuleConfigurationProperties' of type [org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.encrypt.SpringBootEncryptRuleConfigurationProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-04-26 14:39:40.552  INFO 42043 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.shardingsphere.shadow-org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.shadow.SpringBootShadowRuleConfigurationProperties' of type [org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.shadow.SpringBootShadowRuleConfigurationProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-04-26 14:39:40.555  INFO 42043 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.shardingsphere-org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.common.SpringBootPropertiesConfigurationProperties' of type [org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.common.SpringBootPropertiesConfigurationProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-04-26 14:39:40.605  INFO 42043 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.SpringBootConfiguration' of type [org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.SpringBootConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2a72cc1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-04-26 14:39:41.307  INFO 42043 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-04-26 14:39:41.347  INFO 42043 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-04-26 14:39:41.347  INFO 42043 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2022-04-26 14:39:41.676  WARN 42043 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController' defined in file [/Users/shailendrachauhan/gitworkspace/ShardingPOC/target/classes/com/practice/StudentController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentMapper' defined in file [/Users/shailendrachauhan/gitworkspace/ShardingPOC/target/classes/com/practice/mapper/StudentMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/baomidou/mybatisplus/autoconfigure/MybatisPlusAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shardingDataSource' defined in class path resource [org/apache/shardingsphere/shardingjdbc/spring/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'shardingDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data sources cannot be empty.
2022-04-26 14:39:41.681  INFO 42043 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-04-26 14:39:41.728  INFO 42043 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-04-26 14:39:41.734 ERROR 42043 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentController' defined in file [/Users/shailendrachauhan/gitworkspace/ShardingPOC/target/classes/com/practice/StudentController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentMapper' defined in file [/Users/shailendrachauhan/gitworkspace/ShardingPOC/target/classes/com/practice/mapper/StudentMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/baomidou/mybatisplus/autoconfigure/MybatisPlusAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shardingDataSource' defined in class path resource [org/apache/shardingsphere/shardingjdbc/spring/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'shardingDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data sources cannot be empty.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.practice.StarterApp.main(StarterApp.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentMapper' defined in file [/Users/shailendrachauhan/gitworkspace/ShardingPOC/target/classes/com/practice/mapper/StudentMapper.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/baomidou/mybatisplus/autoconfigure/MybatisPlusAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shardingDataSource' defined in class path resource [org/apache/shardingsphere/shardingjdbc/spring/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'shardingDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data sources cannot be empty.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1362) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/baomidou/mybatisplus/autoconfigure/MybatisPlusAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shardingDataSource' defined in class path resource [org/apache/shardingsphere/shardingjdbc/spring/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'shardingDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data sources cannot be empty.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:508) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1467) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shardingDataSource' defined in class path resource [org/apache/shardingsphere/shardingjdbc/spring/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'shardingDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data sources cannot be empty.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:455) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:855) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'shardingDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data sources cannot be empty.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data sources cannot be empty.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145) ~[guava-31.0.1-jre.jar:na]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.core.rule.ShardingRule.<init>(ShardingRule.java:76) ~[sharding-core-common-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.api.ShardingDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(ShardingDataSourceFactory.java:48) ~[sharding-jdbc-core-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.SpringBootConfiguration.shardingDataSource(SpringBootConfiguration.java:103) ~[sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.SpringBootConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2a72cc1.CGLIB$shardingDataSource$0(<generated>) ~[sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.SpringBootConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2a72cc1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c8f20989.invoke(<generated>) ~[sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.shardingsphere.shardingjdbc.spring.boot.SpringBootConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c2a72cc1.shardingDataSource(<generated>) ~[sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I found one post: [sharindsphere faqs][1]
[1]: https://shardingsphere.apache.org/document/current/en/reference/faq/#jdbc-why-there-may-be-an-error-when-configure-both-shardingsphere-jdbc-spring-boot-starter-and-a-spring-boot-starter-of-certain-datasource-poolsuch-as-druid

I tried removing the mybatis dependency from the pom.xml but didn't get any luck.
Does anyone has faced the same issue? What am i doing wrong here? Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: In the information you provided， `Data sources cannot be empty`  is more important， Can you provide more information about dependencies ? Perhaps this line of code can solve the problem `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`